# How to get distinct values in string array via Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string array:

```
string[] initValue =
{"A=Test11,B=Test12,B=TestA,C=Test14,D=Test15",
 "A=Test21,B=Test22,B=TestA,C=Test24,D=Test25",
 "A=Test31,B=Test32,B=TestA,C=Test34,D=Test35"};
```

And I need the distinct values that start with "B=" and are not "B=TestA", example:

```
string[] resultValue =
{"Test12",
 "Test22",
 "Test32"};
```

How can I use Linq to get this result?

Comment: You have no strings in that array that starts with B= . A comma doesn't start a new string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] result = initValue.Select(v => v.Split(','))
    .SelectMany(v => v)
    .Select(v => v.Split('='))
    .Where(v => v[0] == "B" && v[1] != "TestA")
    .Select(v => v[1]).Distinct().ToArray();
```

First, you need to get the partial strings.
Then You reduce the resulting collections to one.
Then split the individual strings by "=" and select only those that have "B" as first value and not "TestA" as second.
Then select the second value and call `Distinct`, which removes duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Domysee's answer is fine. But one can always throw a Regular Expression to the mix for fun.

```
 var re = new Regex(@"B=(?<test>Test\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
 string[] resultValue = re.Matches( String.Join(",", initValue))
               .OfType<Match>()
               .Select(m => m.Groups["test"].Value)
               .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get your expected result:

```
         var resultValue = initValue
            .SelectMany(s => s.Split(','))
            .Where(x => x.StartsWith("B"))
            .Where(s => s != "B=TestA")
            .Select(a => a.Replace("B=", "")).ToList(); //or .ToArray();
```